Неправильный формат записи байтов в файл
Я преобразую текст в массив байтов и записываю его в файл. Открывая этот файл я вижу всё тот же текст, а не массив байтов, как это можно исправить?
string test = "qwerty";
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("FileName.txt", FileMode.Create))
{
   fileStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test).Length);
}


начнём с того, что любой текстовый файл - это тот же самый бинарный файл, просто с указанием на то что он текстовый, и на его кодировку. FileStream - это обычный Stream, в который вы можете записывать/считывать байты напрямую. По-этому, когда вы получаете байтовое представление текста, и записываете его в fileStream, то это ничем не отличается от записи текста в файл. Если же вы хотите записать байты в текстовом виде, типу [0x10,0x15,...], то вам нужны сначала создать такую строку, а затем её записать

для этого вы можете сделать что то типу bytesText = $"[{string.Join(", ", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test).Select(@byte => $"0x{@byte.ToString("X2")}))}] и уже затем записать в fileStream такое: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bytesText)

а вообще, есть уже готовые методы для создания файла из текста. Я бы просто воспользовался ими: File.WriteAllText("FileName.txt", bytesText)

Приведите пример правильного формата.

Можно ещё так сделать: File.WriteAllText("FileName.txt", "byte array").

Просто поменяйте расширение файла с .txt на .bin - вот вам и будет счастье! Или у вас цель зашифровать файл, чтобы никто не мог видеть содержимое?

Можно использовать такой вариант:
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        string test = "qwerty";
        File.WriteAllText("FileName.txt", String.Join(", ", test.Select(s => (int)s)));
    }
}

type FileName.txt


113, 119, 101, 114, 116, 121


.ToCharArray() можно опустить

@iikuzmychov Кстати, да.

Текстовые файлы автоматически преобразуют байты в текст, т.к. текст по сути и является набором байтов. Чтобы в текстовом файле были байты, нужно создать строку из массива байтов и записать в файл уже ее.

это такой ответ?
